# how do we prevent restriction enzyme of bacteria to cut and destroy our new recombinant?

Tags: cloning

Based on cloning principle, the new DNA recombinant will be introduced to host cells, commonly bacteria, how do we prevent restriction enzyme of bacteria to cut and destroy our new recombinant ?

Comment: I have a few questions: What do you mean by "cloning principle"? What is a "DNA recombinant" for you, a plasmid?

Answer (score 3):

You're essentially looking for a [restriction modification system](http://www.intechopen.com/source/html/38530/media/image1.png). You modify the restriction sites with methyl groups in a way that blocks restriction enzymes from accessing them. The DNA methylation should also be maintained through replication. So if you have an EcoRI site, you can use an [EcoRI methylase](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P00472) to block the action of EcoRI.